# how to synchronize functions with promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

hi i'm trying to synchronize my functions with convert [callback](/questions/tagged/callback) to [promise](/questions/tagged/promise).
i want to add to all posts, **post.authorName** field via forEach loop and query to **user collection**.
first i tried with callbacks but this is [async](/questions/tagged/async) and i need to a [sync](/questions/tagged/sync) tool.
so i use [promise](/questions/tagged/promise) but still my result is like callback.
this is my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient();
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blog";
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var listPosts = function(req, res) {
    find('post', {}, 10, {author: 1})
        .then(function(posts) {

            var myPosts = posts;

            const promises = [];

            myPosts.forEach(function(post) {

                console.log("hi i'm forEach" + '\n');
                console.log(post);
                console.log('\n');

                const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
                        .then(function(postAuthor){
                            post.authorName = postAuthor;
                        })
                        resolve(); 
                });

                console.log("i'm end of forEach and this is result:");
                console.log(post);
                console.log('\n');

                promises.push(promise);
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {

                console.log('i should print at end' + '\n');

            });
        });
}

var getPostAuthorName = function(authorID) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        findOne('user', {_id: new ObjectId(authorID)})
            .then(function(result){

                console.log("i'm getPostAuthorName" + '\n');

                resolve(result.name);
            })
    })
}

var find = function(collection, cond = {}, limit = 0, sort = {}) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mongo.connect(url) 
            .then(function(db){
                db.collection(collection)
                    .find(cond).limit(limit).sort(sort).toArray()
                        .then(function(result){
                            resolve(result);
                        })
            })
    });
}

var findOne = function(collection, cond = {}){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mongo.connect(url)
            .then(function(db){
                db.collection(collection).findOne(cond)
                    .then(function(result){

                        console.log("i'm findOne" + '\n');

                        resolve(result);
                    })
            })
    })
}


listPosts();
```

and at the end i recieve this result:

```
hi i'm forEach

{ _id: 59888f418c107711043dfcd6,
  title: 'FIRST',
  content: 'this is my FIRST post',
  timeCreated: 2017-08-07T16:03:13.552Z,
  authorID: '5987365e6d1ecc1cd8744ad4' }


i'm end of forEach and this is result:
{ _id: 59888f418c107711043dfcd6,
  title: 'FIRST',
  content: 'this is my FIRST post',
  timeCreated: 2017-08-07T16:03:13.552Z,
  authorID: '5987365e6d1ecc1cd8744ad4' }


hi i'm forEach

{ _id: 598d60d7e2014a5c9830e353,
  title: 'SECOND',
  content: 'this is my SECOND post',
  timeCreated: 2017-08-07T16:03:13.552Z,
  authorID: '5987365e6d1ecc1cd8744ad4' }


i'm end of forEach and this is result:
{ _id: 598d60d7e2014a5c9830e353,
  title: 'SECOND',
  content: 'this is my SECOND post',
  timeCreated: 2017-08-07T16:03:13.552Z,
  authorID: '5987365e6d1ecc1cd8744ad4' }


i should print at end

i'm findOne

i'm getPostAuthorName

i'm findOne

i'm getPostAuthorName
```

why functions don't run synchronously.
what's the solution?

Comment: Could you please reduce the problem to a specific question and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: you can answer only one question: does **promise** guarantee sync programing?

Comment: No, of course not. Promises are a just a better way to deal with asynchrony. You shouldn't try to make asynchronous tasks synchronous.

Comment: avoid the Promise Constructor Anti-Pattern - `getPostAuthorName` returns a Promise, no need to wrap the call in a promise ... and in turn, `findOne` and `mongo.connect` also return Promises, so, no need to wrap those in a Promise constructor either

Comment: `does promise guarantee sync programing` - quite the opposite, promises guarantee asynchronous programming

Comment: FYI: your code without the anti-pattern and some other tweaks - https://jsfiddle.net/c0uvq2pn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create promises if you don't need them! Instead, make use of the ability to chain promises:

```js
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient();
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blog";
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var listPosts = function () {
  return find('post', {}, 10, {author: 1})
    .then(function (posts) {
      var promises = posts.map(post => getPostAuthorName(post.authorID));
      return Promise.all(promises).then(names => names.map((name, index) => {
        var post = posts[index];
        post.authorName = name;
        return post;
      });
  });
};

var getPostAuthorName = function(authorID) {
  return findOne('user', {_id: new ObjectId(authorID)}).then(author => author.name);
}

var find = function(collection, cond = {}, limit = 0, sort = {}) {
  return mongo.connect(url)
    .then(db => db.collection(db)
      .find(cond)
      .limit(limit)
      .sort(sort)
      .toArray()
    );
};

var findOne = function(collection, cond = {}) {
  return mongo.connect(url).then(db => db.collection(db).findOne(cond));
};


listPosts().then(posts => console.log('Post:', post, ', author: ', post.authorName));
```

Creating unnecessary promises using the `new Promise` constructor is called the [explicit-construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

But that wasn't the only issue in your code: in unnecessary promise in the following snippet made the code so complex that you didn't realize that you resolved the promise before the author's name was found:

```js
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
    .then(function(postAuthor){
      post.authorName = postAuthor;  
    })
  resolve(); // why resolve immediately?
});
```

Instead, it should have been like this:

```js
const promise = getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
  .then(function(postAuthor){
    post.authorName = postAuthor;  
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert a callback to a promise, you can simply make something like that :

```
function functionWithCallback(params, callback)
{
    [...]
    callback(true);
}

function functionWithPromise(params)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        functionWithCallback(params, (done) => {
            if (done)
                return resolve(true);
            reject(false);
        });
    });
}
```

Now, you can synchronize promises with the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword (don't forget to put your function *async*). Example :

```
async function main()
{
    const p1 = functionWithPromise('1');
    const p2 = functionWithPromise('2');

    await p1;
    await p2;
    console.log('End');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue is with this (badly indented) code

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
        .then(function(postAuthor){
            post.authorName = postAuthor;
        })
        resolve(); 
});
```

Properly indented it looks like

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
        .then(function(postAuthor){
            post.authorName = postAuthor;
        })
    resolve(); 
});
```

So it's clear that `resolve` is called "synchronously" with respect to `getPostAuthorName` - but before the `.then` of `getPostAuthorName` (which is asynchronously called) could be possibly called - hence why your `promises` array is all resolved too early

so, if you move it

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
        .then(function(postAuthor){
            post.authorName = postAuthor;
            resolve(); 
        })
});
```

Now, your code should behave as you expect

Addressing the "promise constructor anti-patterns" in your code - of which the above is an example

Since `getPostAuthorName` returns a Promise, there's no need to do

```
const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
        .then(function(postAuthor){
            post.authorName = postAuthor;
            resolve(); // resolves to "undefined"
        })
});
```

This is equivalent to

```
const promise = getPostAuthorName(post.authorID).then(function(postAuthor){
    post.authorName = postAuthor;
    return; // returns "undefined", just like your resolve() results in
});
```

So, removing all those anti-patterns, and using

```
Promise.all(posts.map(
```

instead of building an array with push

would result in code like

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient();
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/blog";
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const listPosts = function(req, res) {
    find('post', {}, 10, {author: 1})
    .then(posts => 
        Promise.all(posts.map(post => 
            getPostAuthorName(post.authorID)
            .then(postAuthor => post.authorName = postAuthor)
        ))
    )
    .then(() => console.log('i should print at end' + '\n'));
}

const getPostAuthorName = authorID => 
    findOne('user', {_id: new ObjectId(authorID)})
    .then(result => result.name);


const find = (collection, cond = {}, limit = 0, sort = {}) => 
    mongo.connect(url) 
    .then(db => 
        db.collection(collection)
        .find(cond)
        .limit(limit)
        .sort(sort)
        .toArray()
    );

const findOne = (collection, cond = {}) => 
    mongo.connect(url)
    .then(db => 
        db.collection(collection)
        .findOne(cond)
    );
```

> I think I fell into the trap again .. I bet `posts` isn't a javacript Array - in that case I would make a function like

```
const makeArray = collection => {
    const ret = [];
    collection.forEach(item => ret.push(item));
    return ret;
};
```

and change

```
        Promise.all(posts.map(post =>
```

to

```
        Promise.all(makeArray(posts).map(post =>
```